# win2003 server problem

Tags: windows-server-2003

I used to have a server with win2000 OS. Yesteday I updated it to win2003 server R2 service pack 2. My problem now is that in a particular moment nobody can access the server. All of the shared resource of the server are unavailable. The only solution is to restart the server although the server is running fine.

I don't think that is a connection problem of the LAN, because with the win2000 this problem didn't happend. The PC is connected to the same switch and the PC have the same exact hardware.

Comment: "The only solution is to restart the server although the server is running fine."  - So restarting the server does or doesn't fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, it does fix the issue, but I can't restart the server everytime this happens.

Comment: Do you actually need to restart the whole server, or would just restarting the "Server" service do just as well? Are you getting any errors in your event logs mentioning permission errors or services stopping?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your client computers have their DNS entries set to the IP address of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Are they in a domain/AD, a workgroup or simply standalone machines? It really depends on the setup, how about you give us the exact error message and an idea of the setup (IP addresses, subnet masks) and are you sure the resources are really shared?

Comment: The server is in a workgroup. Like twenty machines are connect to it. I don't get an error message, but when I tried to browse the files that the server had shared my explorer freeze.

Answer (score 1):

R2 made some significant changes to network settings by default, I would check you have recent drivers that are compatible. [This article](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2007/04/24/common-networking-issues-after-applying-windows-server-2003-sp2-on-sbs.aspx) while for SBS describes the issue well